# Reading message(data) from TCPServer Buffer by using StreamReader.ReadLine() in TCPClient(ReadLine() doesn't return until a disconnection)

Tags: c#, tcpclient, streamreader, readline, tcpserver

[image: hercules program which creates a TCPServer]
[image: my_form]

I have problem with `StreamReader.ReadLine()` method.I wrote a C# program, but only TCPclient side. I'm using Hercules program to create a TCPServer. I entered the port number and made a connection. Then I ran my program and clicked to Connect button. then, I had connection with TCPServer.

I have no problem with sending data from TCPClient to Hercules(TCPServer). As you see in the picture, I'm entering the string into "Entered to Send" EditText, then I clicked to `Send` button and I sent the String.(we can observe the sending data from the *Received data* part.)

Until here, I have no problem. After sending part, I cannot send data from hercules(TCPServer) to TCPClient. In order to send data, I wrote data into the  ***Send*** part and clicked the `Send` button. after that, to see the coming data you should click the `Show` button .....the problem is right here. I can not read the data from the *ReadStream Buffer*. I debugged my program and I found the problematic part which is:

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string gelen;
            gelen = read_stream.ReadLine();
            txtReceive.Text = gelen;
            MessageBox.Show(gelen, "you have message from server");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("message could not taken !!!");
        }
    }
```

inside the `try` part the line;

```
gelen = read_stream.ReadLine();
```

has problem .ReadLine() is not reading the data from buffer. here is the interesting part, when you send data and click the `Show` button the program freezes, but if you close the connection from `hercules.png` by clicking `Close` button, `read_stream.ReadLine();` is taking the data and putting into the ***Received:*** EditText.

- why it takes the data, after disconnection from TCPServer?
- May be the `\r\n`  characters are the problem?
- I thought that it is waiting for next character. So, when I disconnected it works because it realizes three is no more character. My question is that:

How can I use *read_stream.ReadLine();* to take sending data without disconnection?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    using System.Threading;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data;

    namespace CSharpVeriDenemesi
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Burda server da tanımladıklarımızdan farklı olarak TcpClient sınıfı ile serverdan gelen bilgileri alıyoruz
    public TcpClient Client;
    private NetworkStream network_stream;
    private StreamReader read_stream;
    private StreamWriter write_stream;

    private string local_host = "localhost";
    private int port_number = 8001;
    public TcpListener listener;
    // IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

    public Form1()//form oluşunca otomatik oluşturulan fonksiyon
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//CONNECT
    {
        try
        {
            Client = new TcpClient(local_host, port_number);//İlk parametre bilgisayar adı ikincisi ise port numarasıdır.
            MessageBox.Show("Baglandi");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Baglanamadi");
            return;
        }
        network_stream = Client.GetStream();
        read_stream = new StreamReader(network_stream);
        write_stream = new StreamWriter(network_stream);

    }

    private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//DISCONNECT
    {
        txtSend.Text = "Disconnect clicked";
        try
        {
            write_stream.Close();
            read_stream.Close();
            network_stream.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Düzgün kapatilamiyor !!!" );
        }
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//send ve receive text.box'larını resetliyor.
    {
        txtSend.Text = "";
        txtReceive.Text = "";     
        MessageBox.Show("Reset'e basıldı");          
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//sayfa ilk açıldığında olcaklar için açılan dosya
    {

    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//veriyi server'a gönderiyor
    {

        try
        {
            write_stream.WriteLine(txtSend.Text);
            write_stream.Flush();  //veriyi gönderiyor
            MessageBox.Show("Veri gönderildi");
        }
        catch {
            MessageBox.Show("Veri gönderilmedi !!!");          
        }            
    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string gelen;
            gelen = read_stream.ReadLine();
            txtReceive.Text = gelen;
            MessageBox.Show(gelen, "you have message from server");
        }
        catch
         {
            MessageBox.Show("message could not taken !!!");
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

here is my main.cs I forgot to add it. you can write it and try my project...
note: here is the link for hercules it is portable, you can run it easily [http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html]  [3](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html)

Comment: Can you provide details on the sending application code block? Perhaps it is not flushing the stream?

Comment: It's probably problems with line-endings as you suspect. How do you send the line endings from the server applications? Will it create proper line endings if you input e.g. "\n" or will it send the two characters "\" and "n"? Have you tried sending hex `0x0a` instead?

Comment: no it is flushing, because I can read the data when I close the Hercules. I couldn't read data while Hercules(TCPServer) is connected @rmayer06

Comment: I canNot manage the server side,I am using a program which is Hercules to create server side. It has its own standarts, so I can't change them @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server side doesn't use **`Stream.WriteLine("something..");`** then you will always have to wait for **`End of line char (\r or \n or \r\n)`** at client side when using ReadLine() function.

So the ReadLine() will complete only when connection is closed => your problem.

Your code:

```
        write_stream.WriteLine(txtSend.Text);
        write_stream.Flush();  //veriyi gönderiyor
```

is used at client side, to feedback server, it has no meaning with server sending data.

Try your client side by Reading char by char, or use Read() with BUFFER in specific length.